# mapbox gl js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am creating a map with MapBox GL JS. I created one map on my index.html page and that works fine but now I am trying to create another map on a separate page and when referencing the div where the map should go, I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null.

I am not sure why this is happening since I created the element in my html and my javascript is identical to the javascript that successfully creates the first map on the index.html page (but on a different div). I am doing this in Node.js and bundle with webpack into a main.min.js file, which I reference on both index.html and the second html page.

```js
"use strict"
//here is the MapBox GL JS code at the point the error references in the console
 //_setupContainer: function() {
   //     var container = this._container;
     //   container.classList.add('mapboxgl-map');

// here is my mapbox new map creation 

const ACCESSTOKEN = < my access token >;
mapboxgl.accessToken = ACCESSTOKEN;
const map2 = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map2', 
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
  center: [0,0], 
  zoom: 8.5, 
  pitch: 45, 
  bearing: 27,
  hash: false
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Mapbox example</title>
   <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />  
   <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v1.1.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />  
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="map2"></div> 
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.5/leaflet.js">    </script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v1.1.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that the *div container* that should wrap the *mapbox-gl canvas* is missing.

Here is an example that reproduces the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/y933wwys/ (You can see the error in the web console)

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map2', // <- missing div!
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v8',
  center: [12.338, 45.4385],
  zoom: 1
});
```

You can see that a div with id `map2` is missing. If you replace `map2` with `map` (the id of the existing div), the map is being displayed as expected.

In your case, I would verify that the div map2 exists at the time, you init the map. Maybe it has something to do with the way you bundle the app.